# Generalization of homotopy groups: can we replace $S^n$ by other spaces?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

For a given topological space $X$, the fundamental group $\pi_1(X)$ is defined by homotopy equivalence classes of continuous map $f : S^1 \to X$. Similarly, the $n^{\text{th}}$ homotopy group $\pi_n(X)$ is defined by homotopy equivalence classes of $f : S^n \to X$. My question is, can we generalize this concepts by replacing $S^1$ or $S^n$ to other spaces, such as projective spaces or Grassmanians?

Comment: Yes, in general you can consider the set of homotopy classes of maps from one space $Y$ to another space $X$, which is usually denoted $[Y,X]$. It is usually the case that $Y$ and $X$ are pointed, and then the set is that of pointed maps and homotopies relative to the base point. More generally, you can consider based pairs $(X,A)$.

Comment: One issue is that when you generalize this to other spaces, you might lose some structure. For instance, the group structure on $\pi_n(X)$ is intimately associated with the mathematical fact that the connected sum of two $n$-spheres is an $n$-sphere; if $Y$ does not have that property, you won't be able to define a group structure in the same way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Short Answer:** You can, but you might lose the group structure.

---

Your definitions of $\pi_1(X)$ and $\pi_n(X)$ are not correct - you're missing basepoints.

Fix a basepoint $p \in S^n$ and let $X$ be a topological space. Given $x_0 \in X$, $\pi_n(X, x_0)$ is the collection of maps $f : S^n \to X$, with $f(p) = x_0$ (often called *pointed maps*) up to homotopy relative to $\{p\}$ (sometimes called *basepoint-preserving homotopy*).

For $n = 0$, $\pi_0(X, x_0)$ can be identified with the set of connected components of $X$; it is independent of the choice of basepoint $x_0$ so we just write $\pi_0(X)$. If $X$ is path-connected, then for $n \geq 1$, $\pi_n(X, x_0)$ is independent of $x_0$ and we just write $\pi_n(X)$; if $X$ is not path-connected, $\pi_n(X, x_0) = \pi_n(C)$ where $C$ is the path-connected component of $X$ containing $x_0$.

Moving towards your question, if $Y$ and $Z$ are pointed spaces, denote the collection of basepoint-preserving homotopy classes of pointed maps $Y \to Z$ by $[Y, Z]_{\bullet}$. With this notation, we see that $\pi_0(X) = [S^0, X]_{\bullet}$, and if $X$ is path-connected $\pi_n(X) = [S^n, X]_{\bullet}$ for $n \geq 1$ (if $X$ is not path-connected, $[S^n, X]_{\bullet} = \pi_n(C)$ where $C$ is the path-connected component of $X$ containing $x_0$).

If you fix a pointed topological space $A$, then for any other pointed topological space $X$, $[A, X]_{\bullet}$ is a well-defined set you may wish to study. If you're willing to accept the Axiom of Choice, then any non-empty set can be equipped with a group structure (in fact, [this is equivalent to the Axiom of Choice](https://mathoverflow.net/q/12973/21564)). Now $[A, X]_{\bullet}$ will always be non-empty (it contains the equivalence class of the constant map from $A$ to the basepoint of $X$), so it can be equipped with a group structure, but not in a natural way. First of all, there could be more than one group structure to put on a set of a given cardinality, which one do you choose? On the other hand, the group structure on $\pi_n(X)$ is constructed in a way that doesn't depend on $X$ - it is *natural in $X$*. That is, if $Y$ is another pointed space and $g : X \to Y$ is a pointed map, there is an induced map $g_* : \pi_n(X) \to \pi_n(Y)$ given by $[f] \mapsto [g\circ f]$ which is a homomorphism of groups. As this is a useful property, you may want to require the same of the groups $[A, X]_{\bullet}$.

A pointed topological space $A$ such that $[A, X]_{\bullet}$ is a group for every $X$, and the group structure is natural in $X$ (in the previous sense), is precisely a cogroup object in $\mathsf{hTop}_{\bullet}$, the homotopy category of pointed topological spaces - such a space is sometimes called an *$H$-cogroup*. More generally, a cogroup object in a category $\mathsf{C}$ is an object $A$ such that $\operatorname{hom}_{\mathsf{C}}(A, X)$ is a group for every object $X$, and the group structure is natural in $X$.

From the above, we know that the spheres $S^n$ for $n \geq 1$ are cogroup objects in $\mathsf{hTop}_{\bullet}$, but $S^0$ isn't ($\pi_0(X)$ is just a set). You may hope that there are other cogroup objects, and there are. For any pointed topological space $B$, its [reduced suspension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspension_(topology)) $\Sigma B$ is a cogroup object in $\mathsf{hTop}_{\bullet}$ - this is why spheres $S^n$ for $n \geq 1$ are examples, because $S^n = \Sigma S^{n-1}$. While suspensions provide many examples of cogroup objects, there are [cogroup objects which are not suspensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1524885/39599).

You asked about projective spaces and Grassmannians. Of course, these will give rise to sets, but are they cogroup objects in $\mathsf{hTop}_{\bullet}$? It turns out that the answer is no. In fact, [the only (positive-dimensional) compact connected manifolds which are cogroup objects are spheres](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1414136/is-the-nth-homotopy-group-isomorphic-to-tn-x/1862712#1862712).